# entity framework join 2 tables without modifying domain models

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, join

hey new to entity framework and i have these 2 models

**SynchronizationProfile**

```
public class SynchronizationProfileDBEntity
    {
        public string SyncProfileId { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public SynchronizationType SyncType { get; set; }
        public string Schedule { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
     }
```

**SynchronizationLog**

```
public class SynchronizationLogDBEntity
    {
        public string SyncLogId { get; set; }
        public string SyncProfileId { get; set; }        
        public DateTime Ts { get; set; }
        public SyncLogStatus LogStatus { get; set; }        
        
    }
```

there are no foreign keys on these because my team doesnt do it and get the results directly with **LINQ**

i want to get everything from **SynchronizationLog**(table) + **Code**(which is the name for everySyncProfileId)  property from **SynchronizationProfile**

So i tried left join but for some reason dont get me the results.

```
var profiles = (from item in context.SynchronizationLogs 
                             join item2 in context.SynchronizationProfiles 
                             on item.SyncProfileId equals item2.SyncProfileId into gj
                             from subitem in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             select new
                              {
                                   SyncLogId = item.SyncLogId,
                                   SyncProfileId = item.SyncProfileId,
                                   Ts = item.Ts,
                                   LogStatus = item.LogStatus
                                   Code = item2.Code
                                }
```

Is my approach wrong?

Comment: Problem that you have not used `subitem` in projection? `Code = subitem.Code`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv yes thank you can you tell me how i would write this in ORACLE SQL?

Comment: Let EF Core to generate SQL `profiles.ToQueryString()` or trace what was sent to database.